# How to attach EC2 instance to a Cisco Router in order to send traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing, cisco

I would like to attach (route) EC2 Linux-based instance to a Cisco Router XRv9000v IOS XR 6.3.1 in order to send traffic.

[image]

In the picture above, the EC2 sends traffic to R1 either outside or within VPC.

Comment: My initial thought was to use a route table, but I tried it and it didn't work. I wonder if it has to be done at the operating system level? You could look at the documentation or automation for the Cisco CSR1000v, which is fairly extensive.

Comment: @Tim yes, my thought too. I'm using XRv9000. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router has to have an interface in the same subnet as your EC2 instance. The interface becomes the default gateway for the instance.

Comment: I have already created an instance EC2 in the same subnet as the router. The question is how to make that interface, a default gateway for the instance.

Comment: That is configured in the OS of the instance, just like any other computer.

Comment: all I need is to create a VM instance in the same subnet as the router is, right? there is no added configuration needed ?

Comment: You need to set the default gateway on the instance to the IP address of the router interface.

Comment: Could you please write me the configuration in an answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the OS of the EC2 instance? For Linux:  "sudo route add default gw <ip address>" For windows, use the network configuration gui.

Comment: ! Thanks!  for the <ip address> I shall give the interface address of the router right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.